# React: page not found when refresh page after deployed to IIS

Tags: reactjs, iis

I deploy a React app to IIS and it displays OK but when I press F5 to reload the page, it shows page not found.

The thing is when I start the app by using "npm start" on Visual Studio Code, it works fine but when it comes to IIS, it shows page not found.

Here is my url when I start by Visual Studio Code:
http://localhost:3000/Test/TestRouter (works fine and F5 OK).

My url when I publish on IIS:
http://localhost/Test/TestRouter (works on first load and when F5 displays page not found).

Here is my code:

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Test from './Test';
import { Link, BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
require('dotenv').config()

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App" >
      <Router basename='/Test'>
        <div>
          <nav>
            <Link to="/TestRouter">Test</Link>
          </nav>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/TestRouter" component={Test} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Test.js

```
import React from 'react';

class Test extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>Hello world</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Test;
```

package.json

```
"homepage": "http://localhost/Test/"
```

Is there anyone can help me so I can reload the page after deployed to IIS without this error?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: I thinl you need to add `.htaccess` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig

Answer (score 0):

In IIS, you can use the **rewrite module** to teach the webserver to respond to all urls by returning your main **index.html** file.

[Reference here](https://www.mattburkedev.com/iis-rewrite-rule-for-single-page-apps/)

**Web.config**

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="SPA Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <!-- match everything by default -->
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <!-- unless its a file -->
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <!-- or a directory -->
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <!-- or is under the /api directory -->
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
            <!-- list other routes or route prefixes here if you need to handle them server side -->
        </conditions>
        <!-- rewrite it to /index.html -->
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Hope that helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HashRouter](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/HashRouter).

```html
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Test from './Test';
import { Link, Route, Switch, HashRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
require('dotenv').config()

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App" >
      <HashRouter basename='/Test'>
        <div>
          <nav>
            <Link to="/TestRouter">Test</Link>
          </nav>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/TestRouter" component={Test} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </HashRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is a simple method to solve this problem, but there will be a '#' in the url.

exemple:

> http://localhost/Test/#/TestRouter